# Swift app crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to make an app that takes a users input of a number of quarters, a number of dimes, a number of nickels, and a number of pennies. I then want to output all that by displaying what they entered in dollars plus whatever change is left. I have the mathematical code that can create the output needed. My only issue is that I can not get my UIButton Calculate to do execute the code after the input is entered. I have 4 text fields(one for each type of coin).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var quarterNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dimeNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nickelNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pennyNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var calculate: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resultOutputLabel: UILabel!

var dollarAmount: Int = 0
var quarterAmount: Int = 0
var dimeAmount: Int = 0
var nickelAmount: Int = 0
var pennyAmount: Int = 0

var quarters: Int = 0
var dimes: Int = 0
var nickels: Int = 0
var pennies: Int = 0


@IBAction func exitButton(sender: UIButton) {
    exit(0)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeTextFields()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func initializeTextFields()
{
    quarterNum.delegate = self
    quarterNum.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    dimeNum.delegate = self
    dimeNum.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    nickelNum.delegate = self
    nickelNum.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    pennyNum.delegate = self
    pennyNum.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
}
@IBAction func userTappedBackground(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
@IBAction func calculate(sender: UIButton) {
    quarters = Int(quarterNum.text!)!
    dimes = Int(dimeNum.text!)!
    nickels = Int(nickelNum.text!)!
    pennies = Int(pennyNum.text!)!

    var quarterCount = Int(quarters * 25)

    //all dimes * 10 gives the amount of dimes in penny value( 10 dimes = 100 pennies)
    var dimeCount = Int(dimes * 10)


    //all nickels * 5 gives the user the nickels in penny value(5 nickels = 25 pennies)
    var nickelCount = Int(nickels * 5)

    //all the pennies * 1 gives the cents value in pennies(10 pennies = 10 pennies)
    var pennyCount = Int(pennies * 1)

    //Adding all the values together to get the total amount of pennies
    //totalPennies = all the values above added together
    var totalPennies = Int(pennyCount + nickelCount + dimeCount + quarterCount)

    var dollarAmount = totalPennies / 100
    totalPennies %= 100;

    var quarterDollars = totalPennies / 25
    totalPennies %= 25;

    var dimeDollars = totalPennies / 10
    totalPennies %= 10

    var nickelDollars = totalPennies / 5
    totalPennies %= 5

    var pennyDollars = totalPennies / 1
    totalPennies %= 1

    resultOutputLabel.text = String("There is/are ",  String(dollarAmount) , " dollar(s), " , String(quarterDollars) , " quarter(s), " , String(dimeDollars) , " dime(s), " , String(nickelDollars) , " nickel(s), " , String(pennyDollars) , " penny/ies. ")

  }
}
```

That is the code I have. The build succeeds and everything compiles, it only has problems after i try to input numbers.

Comment: Well, the thing is, sometimes is shows some error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, but most times, i type in the numbers in each text field and click the calculate button so it can do all the math, and nothing happens, i feel like it isnt sending the text field input into the variables

Comment: Check all of you IBOutlets, delete all IBOutlests and try to reconnect all

Comment: I checked your code on a sample App and it seems to work properly. As @ChathurangaSilva noted its most likely that your IBOutlets are not linked properly

Comment: as you are force unwrap the values from every textfield the value conversion to Int may be issue if proper input is not given, still if you can provide location of error it will be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

These calculations are likely what is causing the crash depending on what you enter into the text fields.

```
quarters = Int(quarterNum.text!)!
dimes = Int(dimeNum.text!)!
nickels = Int(nickelNum.text!)!
pennies = Int(pennyNum.text!)!
```

In general,

```
var x : Int = Int("1") // returns an optional
```

Therefore, you did this:

```
var x : Int = Int("1")!
```

Except, that if the value passed to Int() cannot be converted into an Int, the value returned is nil. And this will cause a crash either at this point or when x is used.

While it adds complexity, you will need to prepare to handle the situation where a string isn't convertible.

```
var x = Int("blah")
if let x = x {
    // conversion to Int success
} else {
    // unable to convert
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will look into trying to handle that situation. The simulation was actually working just fine, I only had to get the keyboard to disappear so i could see the output result.